# windows cmd substring a folder name to name new folder

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I want to copy a sub folder and the files but I will rename the destination folder to substring of the src name. Example 
`set src='test/qwerty--1.2.3rc5` I want the destination folder name to be `1.2.3rc5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which demonstrates splitting up a string using command **FOR** specific for your example source string:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "src=test/qwerty--1.2.3rc5"
for /F "tokens=2* delims=/-" %%I in ("%src%") do set "DestinationFolder=%%J"
echo Destination folder is: %DestinationFolder%
endlocal
```

The string `test/qwerty--1.2.3rc5` is split up because of the delimiters `/` and `-` defined with `delims=/-` and because of `tokens=2*` into three substrings:

1. `test` ... completely ignored.
2. `qwerty` ... assigned to loop variable `I` because of `tokens=2` (not of interest).
3. `1.2.3rc5` ... rest of the string after the delimiters after second substring assigned to loop variable `J` being next character in ASCII table after `I` because of `*` in `tokens=2*`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`